# Error in sort.list(y): 'x' must be atomic for sort list

Tags: r, classification

I am trying to use c50 here what I did

```
train$default<-as.factor(train$default)

result<-C5.0(train[-17],train$default)

finalresult <- predict(result, test)
```

I am trying to run the following command `table(test, Predicted=finalresult)`in the R soft
 but it is giving the following error

```
Error in sort.list(y): 'x' must be atomic for sort list
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not state how `test` looks. Since it is used for a prediction it presumably contains features and the value you want to predict. Assuming `test$answer` is what you want to predict. Try

```
    table(test$answer, Predicted=finalresult)
```

Comment: im getting the following error now 
`All Arguments must have same length`

Comment: You should give more details. What are the dimensions of test and finalresult. What are the relevant data types. Are you using other packages apart from C50? 
The base table is a cross tab and needs equal length arguments.

Comment: BTW in some packages you need to explicitly supply the `newdata` for it to work. If you don't supply it'll use the data you used to train the model. In your case I would try `predict(result, newdata=test)`